# avoiding $scope.soup and using controllerAs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am refactoring existing code that I wrote (which is full of the $scope variable) to follow some best practices. Im trying to use 'this' instead as well as controllerAs syntax.  I have the following html which works:

```
<div ng-hide="card.VIN == 0" class="col-md-7" id="cardAndInfoContainer">
         <list-card card="card"></list-card>
    </div>
```

This is my directive (only relevant parts, it's long):

```
scope: {
 card: '='
},

controller: function ($scope, $controller) {
  $scope.card = {
    VIN: 25,
    status: "fadfda",
    image: "",
  };


  $scope.callServiceFunction = function (id) {
    //call function in a service
    Service.getInfo(id).then(function (data) {
      $scope.card = data;
        }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

},

//controllerAs: 'ctrl',
```

How can I refactor the code to follow the best practices above? Here is what I tried but it did not work:

-html unchanged
-in directive controller:

```
controllerAs: 'ctrl',

scope: {
     card: '='
},
template: template,
controller: function ($scope, $controller) {
 var ctrl = this;

  this.card = {
    VIN:0,
    status: "fadfda",
    image: ""
  };


  this.displayCard = function (id) {
    Service.getInfo(id).then(function (data) {
      $scope.card = data;
        }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
return ctrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left in `$scope` here:

```
Service.getInfo(id).then(function (data) {
  $scope.card = data; 
    }, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Try

```
Service.getInfo(id).then(function (data) {
  ctrl.card = data; 
    }, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

One suggestion is to actually declare named functions and variable objects at bottom of controller

```
 function displayCard(id) {
    Service.getInfo(id).then(function (data) {
      $scope.card = data;
        }, function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

  var card = {
    VIN:0,
    status: "fadfda",
    image: ""
  };
```

Then at top of controller bind all references to objects from bottom

```
controller: function ($scope, $controller) {
   var ctrl = this;

   ctrl.card = card; 
   ctrl.displayCard = displayCard;
```

The benefit is that you easily create a table of contents so to speak at the top of the component and all the business is down below

Comment: thanks. does the controller need to return anything?

Comment: no it doesn't need to return anything. Angular takes care of that

Comment: thanks. so I made the changes you suggested and everything is working except my ng-hide condition: <list card ="card" ng-hide="ctrl.card.VIN==0"></list>. even when ctrl.card.VIN==0 it's not hidden.

Comment: ok the actual element that directive references is in parent scope. If you need directive to manage hide...move `ng-hide` inside template

Comment: I understood what you were saying now. I put it inside the template and it works!

Comment: I know this topic is old, but there is one things which I don´t like with your top/bottom approach.
At the top, you set ctrl.card = card; but defining card, you do much later in the code with var card = {...}; that´s realy bad practise - for example, as card is not already declared in the controller object scope (not agular scope) it could have an value of a card variable defined in a somewhat highter scope, which could lead to unwanted behaviour...